# Defer, Hold, Unevaluated, Inactivate -- which one when?

Tags: core-language, hold, function-comparison

What are some guidelines on which function to select from among the superficially similar functions `Defer`, `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, and `Inactivate`?

Consider, for example:

```
Defer[Defer[Sum[1/k^2, {k, 1, Infinity}]]]
Evaluate @@ %

Hold[Sum[1/k^2, {k, 1, Infinity}]]
ReleaseHold[%]

Unevaluated[Sum[1/k^2, {k, 1, Infinity}]]
Evaluate @@ %

Inactivate[Sum[1/k^2, {k, 1, Infinity}], Sum]
Activate[%]
```

Comment: Re: `HoldForm[]` vs. `Defer[]`, the output of the latter can be copied into a new cell and evaluated, while the former's output will still remain held after copying into a new cell.

Comment: [SO duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions) (does not cover `Inactivate`).

Comment: OK, that "SO duplicate" link helps. Now, where does `Inactivate` fit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SO duplicate [Preventing evaluation of Mathematica expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions) 
does a nice job of explaining the differences among and use-cases for `Defer`, `Hold`, and `Unevaluated`.

Here, I can give at least one use-case for `Inactivate` for which the other functions are less useful (if not completely useless). There are plenty of situations in which I want to control the algebraic steps that *Mathematica* does automatically: sometimes I'm doing derivations---using *Mathematica* to get all of the negative signs right on the first try---where I want to see all of the steps in order that I can write them nicely in a paper later; sometimes I want to show the steps to some students; etc.

The problem is, of course, that *Mathematica* has all kinds of built-in automatic simplifications, and `Simplify` does what it wants. So I use `Inactivate` on some of the functions/`Head`s in the expression in order to stop the unwanted automatic simplifications while still being able to use the *rest* of the automatic simplifications.

Here's a contrived example, taken from a [previous answer of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101962/29734). We're trying to show that the expression

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x])
```

simplifies to

```
- 1/Cos[x]
```

or

```
- Sec[x]
```

but `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` automatically simplifies to `Tan[x]`, so we can't do a `Replace`ment to show the step:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] :> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
(* (1 - Tan[x])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x]) *)
```

Instead, we can `Inactivate` all of the trigonometric functions:

```
expr = Inactivate[(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] :> Sin[x]/Cos[x], Tan | Sin | Cos]
expr // Simplify
% // Activate
(* (1 - Inactive[Sin][x]/Inactive[Cos][x])/(-Inactive[Cos][x] + Inactive[Sin][x]) *)
(* -(1/Inactive[Cos][x]) *)
(* -Sec[x] *)
```

Of course, we could have `Replace`d `Head`s instead, using `sin`, `cos`, etc., but `Activate`/`Inactivate` is a nice programmatic way of doing that that doesn't require a whole bunch of replacement rules, and you have the power of `Activate`ing in steps:

```
Activate[1 - Inactive[Sin][x]/Inactive[Cos][x], Cos]
(* 1 - Sec[x] Inactive[Sin][x] *)
```

which can be quite nice.