# Replacing Tan[x] with Sin[x]/Cos[x]

Tags: replacement, trigonometry

Why doesn't this work?

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
```

I get back:

```
(* (1 - Tan[x])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x]) *)
```

I also tried:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. {Tan[x] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x]}
```

Got the same reply.

I also tried:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> (Sin[x]/Cos[x])
```

Still got the same answer.

And though this is an incorrect substitution, it works:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> Sin[x] + Cos[x]
```

**Update:** Ok, here is what I tried using suggestions from folks below. I started with:

```
(1 - tan[x])/(sin[x] - cos[x]) /. tan[x] -> sin[x]/cos[x]
```

Which gave me:

```
(* (1 - sin[x]/cos[x])/(-cos[x] + sin[x]) *)
```

Then:

```
List @@ %
```

Which gave me:

```
(* {1/(-cos[x] + sin[x]), 1 - sin[x]/cos[x]} *)
```

Then I multiplied numerator and denominator by cos[x]:

```
%*{1/cos[x], cos[x]}
```

Which gave me:

```
(* {1/(cos[x] (-cos[x] + sin[x])), cos[x] (1 - sin[x]/cos[x])} *)
```

Then I did an expand:

```
% // Expand
```

Which gave me:

```
(* {1/(cos[x] (-cos[x] + sin[x])), cos[x] - sin[x]} *)
```

I was surprised that the denominator (first element in list) did not expand. Next:

```
Times @@ %
```

Which gave me:

```
(* (cos[x] - sin[x])/(cos[x] (-cos[x] + sin[x])) *)
```

Then:

```
% // Cancel
```

Which gave me:

```
(* -(1/cos[x]) *)
```

Then:

```
% /. cos[x] -> Cos[x]
```

Which gave me a final answer:

```
(* -Sec[x] *)
```

I actually didn't use the % sign. Rather, I used Shift-Cmd-L (Shift-Ctrl-L on Windows) to replay the output of the previous step, but thought that would crowd things a bit if I put it in here.

Interesting. How would other folks handle this process? It would be interesting to hear.

Comment: Try `Tan -> (Sin[#]/Cos[#] &)`.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but `(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) // Simplify` gives `-Sec[x]`.

Comment: @Rahul I am looking at how to apply pencil and paper type steps to simplify the expression. I am aware of the //Simplify expression.

Comment: @J.M. Gave your suggestion a try, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Your replacement is working, I think. The problem is that *Mathematica* automatically simplifies `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` to `Tan[x]`. If you're going to do step-by-step math, perhaps consider using undefined symbols like `sin[x]` and `cos[x]`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the auto-simplification! (@march, that's the answer I believe.) You'll probably want to use `Activate[]`/`Inactivate[]` here.

Comment: What are trying to accomplish by this substitution? You can get the simplification `-Sec[x]` directly from `(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) // Simplify`. I would think that is more useful for any further computation.

Comment: @m_goldberg I added an update to my original post of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: `Numerator[]`/`Denominator[]` is the kosher way of extracting parts of a rational expression.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question: `expr = (1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x];` and `TrigReduce[expr]` gives `-Sec[x]`.

Answer (score 24):

Mathematica auto simplifies simple trig expressions like these, but you can turn off this setting via `SystemOptions`:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];
```

Now we see your change is left untouched without the need of `HoldForm` and friends.

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
```

> ```
> (1 - Sin[x]/Cos[x])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x])
> ```

Comment: Very nice.  I seem to recall other questions where this option would be useful.  (Just not sure how to find them.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 One example is: [Mathematica Sec and Csc](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101975/4330), but J.M. has already given an answer :).

Answer (score 8):

Mathematica automatically simplifies the `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` after `ReplaceAll (/.)`. `Defer` is a useful function for preventing that:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> Defer[Sin[x]/Cos[x]]

(*(1 - Sin[x]/Cos[x])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x])*)
```

`HoldForm` would also work:

```
(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> HoldForm[Sin[x]/Cos[x]]

(* (1 - Sin[x]/Cos[x])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x]) *)
```

Note that the head `HoldForm` stays in the expression (but not displayed).

```
InputForm[(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] -> HoldForm[Sin[x]/Cos[x]]]

(* (1 - HoldForm[Sin[x]/Cos[x]])/(-Cos[x] + Sin[x]) *)
```

Comment: `Defer[]` or `HoldForm[]` would be the pre-version 10 approach, so it's good to have this here.

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* automatically simplifies `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` to `Tan[x]`. Consider:

```
rules = Tan[x] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
(* Tan[x]
```

Using `RuleDelayed` doesn't help:

```
Tan[x] /. Tan[x] :> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
(* Tan[x] *)
```

Instead, since you are doing step-by-step manipulations anyway, just use non-built-in symbols:

```
(1 - tan[x])/(sin[x] - cos[x]) /. {tan[x] -> sin[x]/cos[x]} // Simplify
(* -(1/cos[x]) *)
```

---

Alternatively, as suggested by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), we can use `Inactivate`:

```
expr = Inactivate[(1 - Tan[x])/(Sin[x] - Cos[x]) /. Tan[x] :> Sin[x]/Cos[x], Tan | Sin | Cos] // Simplify
expr // Activate
(* -(1/Cos[x]) *)
(* -Sec[x] *)
```

We specify that only `Tan`, `Sin`, and `Cos` should be `Inactivate`d by using the pattern `Tan | Sin | Cos` (`Alternatives[Tan, Sin, Cos]`).

Comment: @JHM. It depends, I think. The nice thing about `Inactivate` here is that you can continue to use all of *Mathematica*'s simplification functions (like `Simplify`) on the expression. The only thing that changes is the fact that `Tan`, `Sin`, and `Cos` are essentially treated as non-built-in symbols. (That said, I've never used `Defer`, so I don't know its power.)

Comment: With respect to `Defer[]`: it renders whatever it's enclosing inert to evaluation, up until you copy and paste it into another cell. So, `Defer[Sin[x]/Cos[x]]` will give `Sin[x]/Cos[x]` as output, but if you copy this output into a new cell and evaluate, you get `Tan[x]`. In contrast, trying the same experiment with `HoldForm[]` will not give `Tan[x]`; you need `ReleaseHold[]` for that. (It admittedly is all becoming a bit confusing at this point.)

Comment: @march. Oh, I didn't realize that! `Defer` simply does not evaluate the expression altogether, so you cannot apply simplifications inside it; it may not be useful in some cases.