# Simplify a complex trigonometric equation resulting from constraint solving

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

In the solving of mechanical constraints, I often meet complex trigonometric equation that I have to simplify.

Here the equation I would like to simplify :

[Mathematica notebook presenting the equation](http://filez.univ-amu.fr/5fve2xygno)

Can you help me to simplify this equation ?

I would like **only cos and sin in the equation** (with no more tan, Cotan or Sec functions) and gather the kinematic variables (the functions depending of time) the more possible in the cos and sin functions such as cos(gamma1(t)+psi1(t)).

Here the target that I would like to obtain (made with maple for the moment and I hope to do this with mathematica):

[image: Target of the simplifications that I would like to obtain]

Thanks a lot for your help.

P.S: I put a file attached because the equation is quiet long and have subscripts in the notation which make the equation not nice to present

Comment: I take it that a simple `FullSimplify` didn't meet your needs?

Comment: FullSimplify lasts a very long time and I didn't obtain any result

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can give, because otherwise I doubt the expression can be simplified then.

Comment: % //. {Times[a__, Cos[t_]^2] + Times[a__, Sin[t_]^2] :> Times[a] I try this to remove the cos² + sin² = 1 and after i would like to suppress sec function. I think the more interesting would be to have a simplify fraction with on cos and sin function but no more sec functionj

Comment: Consider performing a preliminary Weierstrass substitution first before trying to simplify. You can then undo the substitution afterwards.

Comment: Why not, but may you detail me your suggestion?

Comment: [(7799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7799)/[(101959)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101959) gives you part of the answer.

Comment: Usually when working with trig polys, arising from mechanisms or otherwise, I do the following. (1) Expand (via `TrigExpand`) so trigs of sums disappear. (2) For each sine or cosine of a distinct variable `t`, add the trig polynomial relation `Sin[t]^2+Cos[t]^2-1. (3) Rename `Sin` and `Cos` so the "variables" are no longer trig functions. I typlically change e.g. `Cos[t]` to `c[t]` and similar for `Sin`. At this point one can use `GroebnerBasis` and other functions from polynomial algebra to work on the input system.