# How to get the numerator of this fraction involving `Csc` or `Sec`?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation, trigonometry

I would like to avoid multiplying explicitely by the denominator, because I'm working with huge fractions.

Consider

```
f[x_,y_] := Cos[x - y]/(Sin[x] Cos[y])+ 1/Sin[x];
```

Mathematica transforms this into `Csc[x] + Cos[x - y] Csc[x] Sec[y]` which I'd like to avoid: my goal is precisely to get rid of the singularities. So I used

```
$PrePrint = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Defer@Sin[z], Sec[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cos[z]} &;
```

but then `Together[f[x,y]]` does not put `f` with a common denominator, and `Numerator` just returns `f[x,y]`.

So how can I get the numerator of `f[x,y]`? It should be `Cos[x - y] + Cos[y]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a system setting as first [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101964) by Chip:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False]
```

Then:

```
expr = Cos[x-y]/(Sin[x] Cos[y]) + 1/Sin[x]
Numerator @ Together[expr]
```

> 1/Sin[x] + Cos[x - y]/(Cos[y] Sin[x])
>
> Cos[x - y] + Cos[y]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> `$PrePrint` is applied after `Out[n]` is assigned, but before the output result is printed.

Try setting

```
$Post = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Defer@Sin[z], Sec[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cos[z]} &;
Cos[x - y]/(Sin[x] Cos[y])
% // Numerator
```

Comment: This forces to print the output, which may be a nuisance if the expression takes dozens of lines. I edited the question, introducing the sum, for which the suggested solution fails.

Comment: Then instead of `$Post`, `$PrePrint`, etc. just use the appropriate transformation rule, e.g. `g = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Defer@Sin[z], Sec[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cos[z]} &;` and `f[x,y] // g // Together // Numerator`

Comment: I see, thank you. A last thing: If I define `h[x_,y_] = f[x,y] // g // Together // Numerator`, then `h[1.1,2.2]` does not evaluate `Cos[2.2]` because of `Defer`. So I changed `g` to `g = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Hold@Sin[z], Sec[z_] :> 1/Hold@Cos[z]} &;` and defined ``h[x_,y_] = f[x,y] // g // Together // Numerator // Releasehold``. It's seems to work, do you see any problem with that?

Comment: @anderstood At a glance, no problem, but I guess, some testing would be needed. I found, that the original approach with `$Post` results in nested `Times[..., Times[...]]` expressions that are cleaned up only when displayed. It's hard to say, whether you'll run into more similar problems for more complicated expressions. Try it out with your actual use case and report back if you run into further problems.