# How to switch Tan[x] for Sin[x]/Cos[x] without Mathematica changing the latter for the former?

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, trigonometry

When I ask Mathematica to do this:

```
(Sin[2 x] - Tan[2 x])/x^3 /. Tan[x_] -> Sin[x]/Cos[x]
```

It makes no change because Mathematica interprets `Tan[x]` as the same thing as `Sin[x]/Cos[x]`. Is it possible to force Mathematica to rewrite:

$$\frac{\sin(2x)-\tan(2x)}{x^3}$$

As:

$$\frac{\sin(2x)-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}{x^3}?$$

I know this has to do with evaluation control but I'm looking at the documentation and am not finding anything that resembles this. At the time, I know I could make this converting everything to  string and using string substitutions but I guess this would be kinda cumbersome for my needs.

Comment: `(Sin[2 x] - Tan[2 x])/x^3 /. Tan[x_] -> HoldForm[Sin[x]/Cos[x]]` ?

Comment: @Syed This is really nice. I was trying some of these functions (Hold, HoldForm, etc) but wasn't sure where is the right place to apply them. I also found a "cheap" way, which is convert the functions I have like Cos[x] to cos[x], make whatever operations I need on it and then convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

Update. Duplicate: [Replacing Tan[x] with Sin[x]/Cos[x]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101959/replacing-tanx-with-sinx-cosx/101964#101964)

---

Set the system option:

```
SetSystemOptions[
 "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];
```

[image]