# How to prevent simplification from Times to Power?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, built-in-symbols

By default, Mathematica simplifies `Times[f[x],f[x]]` as `Power[f[x],2]`. In most cases it's fine, but I happen to have a code where this rule is particularly annoying.

Is it possible to modify the behavior of Times so that this rule is not applied for a particular type of argument (let's call it g) i.e. `Times[g[x],g[x]]` is kept unchanged, but `Times[a,a]` becomes `Power[a,2]` if `a` is a Symbol (or anything except `g`).

Thank you for your help.

Edit : Sorry if I was unclear. I would like this behavior to be applied automatically everywhere in the session. For example, I can modify `Times` by doing :

```
Unprotect[Times]
Times[a_g,a_g]:=Defer[Times[a,a]]
Protect[Times]
```

This work fine, because `Times[f[x],f[x]]` becomes `f[x]^2`, and `Times[g[x],g[x]]` does not change. But with this trick, I'm stuck with the ugly FullForm `Defer[Times[g[x],g[x]]]`, which will mess up my pattern matchings. What I'd really like to do is remove a rule from `Times`, instead of adding one.

Comment: [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html), [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html), [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html)  and appropriate use of [Pattern matching](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html) seems like the crudest solution I can think of. Also [`98874`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98874/defer-hold-unevaluated-inactivate-which-one-when) seems useful.

Comment: I think those functions will only prevent the evaluation temporary. At some point I will have to `ReleaseHold` and `Times[g,g]` will transform. Unless I can use those after unpotecting `Times`. But I still don't see how.

Comment: There may be a way in your particular use-cases.  Without more of the context, we'll probably just be guessing like Sektor.  That is, if anyone wants to take the trouble to guess.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want only powers of `g` handled differently,

```
unique /: Power[unique[x_], n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Inactive[Times] @@ ConstantArray[g[x], n]

grule = g -> unique;

expr1 = g[x]^3 /. grule
```

[image]

```
expr1 // Activate

(* g[x]^3 *)

expr2 = g[3 y + z]^2 /. grule
```

[image]

```
expr2 // Activate

(* g[3 y + z]^2 *)
```

**EDIT**: To have the modification be applied automatically, add the [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) to [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html)

```
$Post := (# /. g -> unique &)

expr = g[x]^3
```

[image]

However, since it is applied automatically, [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) will not cancel the [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)

```
expr // Activate
```

[image]

A different symbol must be used to remove the `Inactive`

```
expr /. g -> \[FormalG] // Activate

(* \[FormalG][x]^3 *)
```

going back

```
% /. \[FormalG] -> g
```

[image]

To clear `$Post` use

```
$Post =.
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I was thinking of a more permanent modification that is applied automatically. I edited my question to make it clear.